# Add as a new version to existing files?

Tags: document-set

In SharePoint 2013 when I upload a document what does this option mean "Add as a new version to existing files?"
Thanks
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What happened to your existing SharePoint files when you tried two uploads, one with, one without that checkbox checked??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upload a file with an already existing filename in the document library, it will overwrite this, creating a new version.

If you uncheck the option "*Add as a new version to existing files*" and upload a file with an already existing filename, the system will trigger an error and will not upload that file.